# How to show the error without mouse hover on the error provider?

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

How to show the error without mouse hover on the error provider ?[image]

```
this.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "This field must contain text");
```

Comment: you could alway add a label next to it and display your error in there... probably not the best, but could work easly

Comment: I've had some experience trying to do this, and this is probably not what you want to hear but I don't think it is possible to do that with a standard Winforms Error Provider. About the only way I can think of doing it is to write your own error provider class - plenty of examples available on the net.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be the best chioce but should work

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
         ErrorProvider myerror = new ErrorProvider();
         ToolTip mytip = new ToolTip();
         myerror.SetError(textBox1, "This field must contain text");
         mytip.Show("This field must contain text", textBox1);
    }
```